# What is the difference between ‘woke’ and ‘awoke’ in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> When the soldiers awoke, it was a bright day.

Can I replace ‘awoke’ by ‘woke’ and why?

Answer (score 2):

The verb "to [wake](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wake)" can be transitive or intransitive.

> *I woke the soldiers at daybreak.*
>   *When the soldiers woke, it was a bright day.*

The verb "to [awake](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/awake)" is always intransitive.

> *When the soldiers awoke, it was a bright day.*

There is a difference in the usage of present participle.

> ✓ *I am awake.*
>   ✗ *I am wake.*

Also there can be a shade of difference in their meaning. The verb "to awake" can be used in the case of a life event, such as

> *My awakening as an adult occurred at the summer camp.*

Comment: However, there a further verb **awaken**, which can be transitive: "His television series awakened popular interest in American architecture."

Comment: @djna good point, I have also extended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "awoke" with "woke". The reason is that they are the past participles of the verbs "awake" and "wake", which have identical meanings.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-awaken-awoken-awakened) very interesting. It seems that there are actually three different verb forms, with a complex relationship in history, and very similar meanings.

So we have wake, awake and awaken as three different verbs with very similar meanings. We can say:

```
I woke
I awoke
I awakened
```

and all three mean more or less the same thing.

There is the additional potential confusion of **awake** also being used as a peculiar sort of adjective that is not used with a noun!

In everyday usage I would suggest avoiding **awoke** and **awakened**

```
I woke early this morning.
```

is quite a normal sentence. The use of **awoke** or **awakened** sounds a little archaic or poetic. We might see those forms used in literary works, but in everyday speech they would more often be used in a playful way, pretending to a level of self-importance.